# Calling overriden (derived class) version of a non-virtual base class function from inside base class?

Tags: c++, overriding, virtual, vtable

So, if I have

```
class base
{
  public:
  virtual void start();
  virtual void stop();

  void doSomething() { start(); .... stop(); }
}

class derived : public base
{
  public:
   void start();
   void stop();
}
```

calling `derived.doSomething()` will call derived::start() and derived::stop().
BUT this only works if they're virtual.

I wanted to know why it doesn't work without the `virtual` keyword, meaning the lower level details. I can't find much about this online...

Thanks!

Comment: I can recommend the [cppreference.com article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) on virtual functions.

Comment: It doesn't work without `virtual` because `virtual` is how you tell the base class that the function might be overridden in a derived class and thus to figure out at runtime which version to call. Thus the question is really a tautology. It doesn't work without the thing that makes it work! I'm sure there must be plenty of resources about this online.

Answer (score 0):

Without the virtual keyword, base::doSomething code has NO IDEA about the derived version's of those methods (think linker resolution)

Comment: This is pretty much hand-waving. Even with `virtual`, the `doSomething` code has no idea about the derived versions of those functions. `virtual` tells the compiler that derived classes **might** override those functions, and in response the compiler generates code to support overriding. But if the derived class doesn't override those functions, the code is still valid. (`virtual void start() = 0;` would be different, but that's not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @PeteBecker The virtual keyword tells the linker to resolve the call via the virtual table, to be resolved at runtime.  Without it being virtual, the linker resolves it to a static call.  That's what I meant by NO IDEA (statically linked vs. virtual table call that implies SOME IDEA of a possible derived implementation).

Comment: Again: the code generated for the base class doesn’t know anything about any derived classes. It provides a mechanism that **derived classes** can use to override base class virtual functions.

Answer (score 0):

If a function is declared virtual, all overrides of this function are stored in a [virtual member function table (vtable)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table). When such a function is called in your code, the program really just points to the location of the table. The table is then used to determine the correct function to call at runtime.

If a function is not declared virtual, `start()` and `stop()` in the base class implementation of `doSomething` are always just pointing to the base class definition of these functions.

C++ lets you chose between both mechanisms, because the runtime look-up in the vtable results in some overhead, which C++ generally does not force on the user - "you only pay for what you use".

The [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table#Example) and [invocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table#Invocation) sections of the wiki article show the technical side pretty well.